# Cloudforming RDS sqlserver-ee Invalid parameter Combination

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

Trying to cloudform a rds instance running sqlserver-ee  engine:

```
RDS does not support creating a DB instance with the following 
combination: DBInstanceClass=db.t3.small, 
Engine=sqlserver-ee, EngineVersion=15.00.4073.23.v1, 
LicenseModel=license-included.
```

That's clearly not the actual error because I've stood up one from the console using the exact same parameters. Does anyone know how to get the real error / reason this is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message seems correct to me. `sqlserver-ee` is the value for creating an `SQL Server Enterprise Edition` database. If you select that in the RDS Console, it will not allow you to select any instance type that is smaller than `db.t3.xlarge`.

As you have set the instance type to `db.t3.small`, I am assuming you are planning to set up an `SQL Server Express Edition` or `SQL Server Web Edition` instance. In this case the `Engine` parameter needs to be either `sqlserver-ex` or `sqlserver-web`.

Comment: Yeah forgot to update this, that was it. mixed up `ee` and `ex`